# How to decide where to put a function in django fat model implemantation

Tags: python, django, model, fat

I want to know where to put a function on models that related to multiple models.

I have four models:
1- custom user
2- office
3- company
4- vehicle

every vehicle, user and office has a foreign key to company.

I want to have all vehicles from a company

I have tried to put a staticmethod on vehicles to get appropriate vehicles but I am not sure this is the right way of doing things because I have to pass request to models.

```
@staticmethod
def get_current_company_vehicles(request):
    Vehicle.objects.filter(
        located_office__in=CompanyOffice.objects.filter(company=request.user.company).values_list('pk')
    )
```

Where would you guys put the function and how to decide where a functions should go?

Comment: If you are asking for the location only without any technical requirements then I fear your question is opinion based and not suited for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bahadir selam :) I assume you linked those models to company with foreign key. if so
to access a related object you need to go from the opposite model and use **_set**.

```
Company.vehcile_set.all
```

Please next time paste your full code to be much easier.
More information from [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/relations/)